# How to transform a custom datatype to arrays of arrays

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia and I have some difficulties with the programming with types approach.

I wanted to load a 3D mesh from a file to practice and I have made some custom types to store it.

Here are my types:

```
struct Vertex
    x::Number
    y::Number
    z::Number
    Vertex(x::Number, y::Number, z::Number) = new(x, y, z)
    Vertex(t::Tuple{Number, Number, Number}) = new(t[1], t[2], t[3])

    Vertex(x::Number, y::Number) = new(x, y, 0)
    Vertex(t::Tuple{Number, Number}) = new(t[1], t[2], 0)

    Vertex(x::Number) = new(x, 0, 0)
    Vertex(t::Tuple{Number}) = new(t[1], 0, 0)

    Vertex() = new(0, 0, 0)
    Vertex(t::Tuple{}) = new(0, 0, 0)
end

struct Mesh
    t::Vector{Vertex} # List of triangles
    f::Vector{Vertex} # List of faces
    n::Vector{Vertex} # List of normals
    Mesh(t::Vertex, f::Vertex) = new([t], [f], [])
    Mesh(t::Vector{Vertex}, f::Vector{Vertex}, n::Vector{Vertex}) = new(t, f, n)
    Mesh(t::Vector{Vertex}, f::Vector{Vertex}, n::Vector) = new(t, f, n)

    Mesh(t::Vector, f::Vector, n::Vector) = new(t, f, n)

    #Mesh(t::Triangle) = new([t], [])
    #Mesh(t::Vector{Triangle}) = new(t, [])
end
```

I can effectively load a mesh in my **Mesh** type.

Now, I would like to plot it using the method **plot_trisurf** from **PyPlot**. However, this method expect an array of arrays and I'm not sure my way of doing it is the right way:

```
function plotMesh(M)
    Xv = map(e -> e.x, M.t[:])
    Yv = map(e -> e.x, M.t[:])
    Zv = map(e -> e.x, M.t[:])
    Fv = map(e -> (e.x, e.y, e.z), M.f[:])

    plot_trisurf(Xv, Yv, Zv, triangles=Fv, alpha=1)
    gca()[:projection] = "3d"
end
```

**Q**:

- The Xv, Yv, Zv doesn't feel right at the moment,
- and the Fv do not work at all. [**Corrected -> see Edit**]
- What it the best way of doing this?
- Is my type design correct? or should I change it to something more suitable?

Thanks

---

[edit]
After some more tests I finally managed to make it work, however I'm still not sure if it is the best way to do things in Julia nor if my type system is a good one.

```
function plotMesh(M::Mesh)
    Xv = map(e -> e.x, M.t[:])
    Yv = map(e -> e.y, M.t[:])
    Zv = map(e -> e.z, M.t[:])
    Fv = map(e -> [Int(e.x)-1, Int(e.y)-1, Int(e.z)-1], M.f[:])
    print(size(Xv))
    print(size(Fv))

    plot_trisurf(Xv, Yv, Zv, triangles=Fv)
    gca()[:projection] = "3d"
end
```

[First 3D plot in Julia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlcOW.png)

---

[edit]
The vertices and normals are (in general) floats and the faces are integers.

The object I'm using is [bunny.obj](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/Data/Meshes/bunny.obj)
and my code for loading the object in the structures is:

```
function read_obj(filename::String)
    v = []
    f = []
    n = []

    tof(x) = parse(Float64, x)

    open(filename) do file
       for line in eachline(file)
            l = split(line, ' ')
            if l[1] ∈ ["v", "f", "n"]
                values = (tof(l[2]), tof(l[3]), tof(l[4]))
                if l[1] == "v"
                    push!(v, Vertex(values))
                elseif l[1] == "f"
                    faces = (Int(values[1]), Int(values[2]), Int(values[3]))
                    push!(f, Vertex(faces))
                elseif l[1] == "n"
                    push!(n, Vertex(values))
                end
            end
        end
    end

    return Mesh(v, f, n)
end
```

My way of loading the object is surely not the best way of doing it. If you have any material to improve my skills feel free to share :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would change the definition of `Vertex` like this (it seems below you require entries to be integers, if not, you can change `Integer` to `Number`)

```
struct Vertex{T<:Integer}
    x::T
    y::T
    z::T
end

Vertex(x::T=0, y::T=zero(T)) where {T<:Integer} = Vertex(x,y,zero(T))
Vertex(t::Tuple) = Vertex(t...)
```

Next in `Mesh` you can use StructArrays.jl package like this (this way you can easily access fields of `Vertex` as vectors):

```
using StructArrays

struct Mesh{S<:StructArray, T}
    t::S
    f::S
    n::S
    function Mesh(t::Vector{T}, f::Vector{T}, n::Vector{T}) where {T<:Vertex}
        st, sf, sn = StructArray(t), StructArray(f), StructArray(n)
        new{typeof(st), T}(st, sf, sn)
    end
end

Mesh(t::T, f::T) where {T<:Vertex} = Mesh([t], [f], T[])
```

now you can define the plotting function for example as:

```
function plotMesh(M::Mesh{S, T}) where {S,T}
    Fv = eachrow([M.f.x M.f.y M.f.z] .- one(T))
    print(size(M.t.x))
    print(size(Fv))
    plot_trisurf(M.t.x, M.t.y, M.t.z, triangles=Fv)
    gca()[:projection] = "3d"
end
```

Note 1: All codes make sure that all the structures operate on concrete types so that the code will be faster than using abstract types (like `Number`). Also I make sure that all entries have the same type.

Note 2: I have written this from my head as you did not provide data to test the code against (so please let me know if anything fails in this code). Strictly speaking you do not have to use StructArrays.jl to achieve the goal, but I hope that you will agree that using them gives you a more readable code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to make it work. However, my faces are Integers and my Vertex and Normal are often Floats. I'm trying to do something like: 
```function Mesh(t::Vector{T}, f::Vector{U}, n::Vector{T}) where {T<:Vertex, U<:Vertex}``` but it do not work yet. I upload some code in the main post :)

Comment: In this case it will be simplest for you to convert everything to `Float64` (you could do it differently, but this should be enough for your purposes). In other words - keeping Faces as floats should simplify your code and should not introduce new problems (unless you would use very large integers - over 52 bits, which is not likely).